# Why my script BAT stop at the second line and display (END)?

Tags: git, batch-file

I have simplified an ancient script to read a file line by line after see example on the web. I have a file.txt with some number in each line and i want to use each of these line to a git command.

But when i run my .bat, it stops at the second line.

The **file.txt** (I precise there is some LF behind each number if it could help):

```
365
369
389
393
413
417
437
491
515
566
587
610
681
887
964
```

And after my **batch.bat** :

```
for /F %%a in (..\log_test\file.txt) do (
    git blame -L %%a,+1 ..\..\path\to\file.cpp -e

    )
```

The blame command take the number **365** and **369** but doesn't continue after, display **(END)** and doesn't close. I found a lot of examples on this site but i can't see where is my error ?

Is there a way to give the value of each line to my git command ?

**Solution :**

```
for /F %%a in (..\log_test\file.txt) do call:test %%a
pause
exit/b

:test
echo Treating :[%1]
set /a a = %1
echo %a%
git blame -L %a%,+1 ..\..\to\path\file.cpp -e >> listEmail.txt
echo %errorlevel%
```

Thanks

Comment: You could try `echo git blame ....` to see what would be done. And you could try `call git blame ...`  to avoid problems when your `git` command is itself a batch wrapper for git.exe

Comment: @jeb When i use `echo` it display well all the line, but naturraly does nothing. And with the `call` it still stop at the second line.

Comment: could it be that `git blame` modifies `log_test\file.txt`?

Comment: Just to understand your git command better: What does `,+1` do?

Comment: @sjoy I will verify that beacause, it seems that's the problem. When i put +0, the command says error but the script continue as expected. But instead, my git command is no longer good...

Comment: Yes, if you're using it to increment, get rid of it completely and test. Just:
-L %%a ..\ etc

Comment: In fact it's to say how many lines the git command display after... I think i have to work on that...

Comment: yes. Looks like line spec should go after -L and before %%a. Maybe `-L 0,+1 %%a`?

Comment: @sjoy Ok i've identified the problem. When I make the command `git blame -L ...` it runs in fact very well but, when the result is too long, I have to press `q` to continue (when it display **(END)**)... I've test manually, step by step. So the problem now is to says type `q` if display (END).... Someone says how ?

Comment: You can't simulate a key-press in batch--that is, you can't have the batch file press `q`. You'll have to find a way to limit the lines of output. If `-L 0,+1` doesn't work, I don't know another way.

Comment: Or, don't use +1. Just starting line, ending line: `-L 0,5` for example

Comment: @sjoy Yes i know. So the way I found, it's to change the way git display information. Like that `git config --global core.pager cat` after the script runs on and i can receipe all the commit line in a text file. Thanks a lot everyone. I edit my post for the final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a call :

```
@Echo Off
for /F %%a in (..\log_test\file.txt) do call:test %%a
exit/b

:test
echo Treating :[%1]
git blame -L %1,+1 ..\..\path\to\file.cpp -e
echo %errorlevel%
```

Comment: what is the rationale?

Comment: @PA I recover this line from an another file.txt ouput by an error of compiling. So i want after blame for each line with an error to recover the email of the last commiter.

Comment: Just to decompose the treatment and try to find where the problem is

Comment: @SachaDee I use your method but it stop at the second line again... Edit : it says treating is not recognize...

Comment: You can maybe check the errorlevel after th Git command to get more information :check my edit

Comment: Yes i've already try this, it display 0 for **365** but when for the next test, it  display the git command fine and display **(END)** just after. And i can't see the level error